# Integration limits for marginal probability density function with circle boundary

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Given the following joint probability density function:

$$f_{XY}(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}, x^2 + y^2 \leq 4, y \gt 0$$

Find the marginal probability density function of Y, i.e $f_Y(y)$.

I know that the boundary is the upper half of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, and that I have to solve the integral $f_Y(y) = \int_a^bf_{XY}(x, y)dx$ but I am having a hard time finding a and b, the limits of the integral because the area is a circle. The probable limits that I have come up with are $-2<x<2$ and $-\sqrt{4-y^2} < x < \sqrt{4-y^2}$. Is any of these correct, and if not, what is the correct limit for the integral?

Comment: The second is right.

Comment: Draw a picture. For any fixed $y$, $x$ travels from the left end $-\sqrt{4-y^2}$ to the right end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The probable limits that I have come up with are $-2<x<2$ and $-\sqrt{4-y^2} < x < \sqrt{4-y^2}$. Is any of these correct, and if not, what is the correct limit for the integral?

It is the second.   You have to ensure you remain within the support for all $X$ with respect to a particular value for $Y~=y$.

The joint density function, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, has a support of $\{(x,y): x^2\leq 4-y^2, 0< y\}$, an upper half circle of radius $2$, so the marginal density function for $Y$ will clearly be the integral $$\begin{align}f_{Y}(y) ~=~& \int\limits_{-\surd(4-y^2)}^{+\surd(4-y^2)} \tfrac 1{2\pi} \operatorname d x\quad\Big[y\in(0;2)\Big]\\[1.5ex] ~=~&\tfrac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{4-y^2~}\qquad\Big[y\in(0;2)\Big]\end{align}$$

---

You can now find the marginal density function for $X$.